# Complete a movie download on different Wi-Fi

Tags: ios, wifi, data-transfer, movie

I am downloading the movie Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire. But because I am using hotel Wi-Fi, it is slow and I will be leaving the hotel before it finishes.

So here is my question: If I disconnect from a network before the movie finishes downloading, but then later connect to a different network, will the movie resume downloading from where it left off?

I am using an iPad mini (don't know if it is 2/3) running iOS 10.2. I am downloading the movie via the iTunes Store.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can you please edit your question to explain _how_ you're actually downloading the movie (i.e. what app are you using, from what site, etc)?

Comment: I am using the iTunes store

Comment: Based on [this](https://support.apple.com/en-la/HT204312), I'd say.... Yes, maybe...  The word they use in that page is "restart", which keeps the whole article a bit vague when it comes to this, but at least in the ios screenshot it says "Resume download".

Comment: I tried it with a song on my ipad, and that at least seems to continue where I left off, after I shut down the connection and/or switched to another network.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you switch to another network, the download resumes from where it was interrupted (the download will pause as long as you not connected to a wifi, in your case).